# View that only intercepts swipe?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I would like to have two gesture recognizer fields in my app for detecting swipe gestures, but I would like them to pass any other forms of interaction (taps, other swipes) down to the views underneath. How would I go about doing this? Do I manually have to pass them down one by one or is there a way to only intercept specific events and allow others to pass through uninterrupted?

Comment: will you explain it little more?

Comment: I have a scrollview from which I want to intercept swipe up events and do something else with, while still maintaining the ability to swipe side to side and tap on the buttons in it.

Comment: You can add gesture recognizer concept to scroll view

Comment: Still not clear what you require.

Comment: Provided your scrollview has only side to side swipe, means scrollview should not support top and bottom swipe.(Scrollview content height should not be more than scrollview height).

Comment: Right now, I have a scrollview that needs to detect scrolling left and right, and taps. It is slightly smaller than the view I have layered on top of it which has two gesture recognizers on it - for swipes up and down. I want the touches and side scrolling to pass down and the swipes up and down to stay with the top view. Is there any way to accomplish this without writing a custom view class do divvy up and pass along the touches?